# available and read: can we actually be nonblocking while using blocking Java I/O?

Tags: java, io, blocking, nonblocking

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695372/what-does-inputstream-available-do-in-java) I would like to ask the following.
Assuming blocking I/O and I have a piece of code like the following:

```
byte[] data = new byte[10];
someInputStream.read(data)
```

This code snippet is going to block in the `read` call until it has some bytes to read. I'm familiar that `read` might actually read less bytes and the number of bytes read is going to be returned by the `read` method.

My question is this. Assume I have:

```
byte[] data = new byte[10];
if (someInputeStream.available() >= 10) {
       someInputStream.read(data); // ***
}
```

Is `***` line guaranteed to not block? Again, I'm aware that this read might still read less than 10 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is guaranteed not to block.

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) for `InputStream`, looking at the `available()` method:

> Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream. The next invocation might be the same thread or another thread. **A single read or skip of this many bytes will not block, but may read or skip fewer bytes.**

(Emphasis mine.)

So it won't block, but (as you say) you might not get the full 10 bytes.

Note that this is assuming a single thread. If there are multiple threads, then of course another thread might have read from the stream between the `available()` and the `read()`.